# Design a Data Structure to compare two XML docs

Tags: xml, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, tree

Given two XML docs. Come up with a data structure and code to compare the two docs and print the differences between the docs. (Like a tag is present in one not in another or tags are same but data is different may be etc)

`My approach` : use N-ary tree. N depends upon the number of attributes in XML file.Now function will be something like :

```
Bool IsIdentical(tree1,tree2)
{
   if(tree1 == NULL && tree2 == NULL)return true;
   if(tree1 || tree2) return false;
    if(tree1->data == tree2->data )return true;
   else return (Isindentical(tree1->firstchild,tree2->firstchild) &&  Isindentical(tree1->secondchild,tree2->secondchild) && ........ Isindentical(tree1->nthchild,tree2->nthchild) )

}
```

can you please tell is my approach is right or is there any other data structure to compare ?
and if my approach is right then please tell how to generate the differences.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is sound. An alternative approach which doesn't require keeping both xml docs simultaneously in memory is to construct the [Merkle tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree) for each doc and compare these.

Comparing the differences is a more open problem and depends on how you define 'difference' between docs. E.g. `<tag 1><tag 2><tag 3>...` vs `<tag 1><tag 3>`, it could be argued that `<tag 1>` is the only common element, or both `<tag 1> & <tag 3>` are common to both.

The most conservative (, and therefore simple) approach will be to declare a difference whenever any children of a node are different and stop recursing at this point, i.e generate the intersection of the 2 trees. An implementation might look something like this:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, children):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children

def intersect(a, b):
    if a.value != b.value:
        return None
    children = [x for x in itertools.imap(intersect, a.children, b.children) if x is not None]
    return Tree(a.value, children)
```

Note that this solution may be overly conservative, depending on your goal.